# lucene.net 4.8 custom sorting according to string length

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

How can I sort by string length?
For example, I use lucene.net to search, the keyword is "toluene", then the name of "toluene" is in the front, and the name containing "toluene" is in the back, which makes me very troubled.

This is my search:

```
var query = MultiFieldQueryParser.Parse(version, GetKeyword(keyword), fileds, new Occur[] { Occur.SHOULD, Occur.SHOULD, Occur.SHOULD, Occur.SHOULD }, analyzer);

foreach (var item in fileds)
{
    var regexpQuery = new RegexpQuery(new Term(item, $".*{keyword}.*"));

    bq.Add(regexpQuery, Occur.SHOULD);
}

Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("name", SortFieldType.SCORE, false));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to sort by string length would be to index a separate field that holds the length of the string.  So if for example your field name is `item` you could add another field that is `itemLength` and index that.  `itemLength` could be a numeric field or a zero padded string field.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but there seems to be a problem if you sort by the length of the string. For example, if I search for methanol, there may be anhydrous methanol and benzyl alcohol. I want users to search for the most matching keywords first. Is there any good way?

Comment: You question was "How can I sort by string length?" and I provided a way to do that.  If you now want to sort some other way, it's best to create a new question and in that question provide details of you you want it to sort.  Clearly defining the requirements is always the first step to finding a way to meet them.